# use get_object_or_404() method with mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm starting to learn Django using Mongodb, creating a poll app following the djangoproject tutorial. I have a problem at the moment of raising a 404 error.
If I do this:

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
 try:
    poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
 except Poll.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
 return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': poll})
```

it works, but if I try to use a django shortcut:

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
  poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
  return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': poll})
```

I get this error

```
Object is of type 'Poll', but must be a Django Model, Manager, or QuerySet
```

I think this error occurs because in models.py I've defined the Poll model as a mongoengine Document and not as a django Model

```
class Poll(Document):
```

What should I do to have the get_object_or_404() method working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's time to roll your own shortcut then?

```python
def get_obj_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return klass.objects.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except klass.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def detail(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_obj_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': poll})
```

I haven't tested it yet but that's the basic idea.

I don't think you are doing anything wrong, it's just that that Django shortcut doesn't support the `Document` class. Check the Django source code, specifically the function [`get_object_or_404()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa6893e9dbb127d70c1376667c700b71bb987fe0/django/shortcuts.py#L57) (which uses the function [`_get_queryset()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa6893e9dbb127d70c1376667c700b71bb987fe0/django/shortcuts.py#L44), the one that raised the exception you got) then I think you will understand.

Comment: thanks it worked! but I'd like to know, if it is possible, why I can't use the shortcut that cames with django, if this is a problem with mongoengine or I am doing something wrong

Comment: no you don't do anything wrong, check my edited answer for more details